# Where can I find an example of a sponsored transaction (ERC-4337)?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens, gas, accounts

I know this is the [standard repo](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction) but I am not finding an actual example on how I can send a transaction from an account, paying for gas fees in an ERC20 token (paymaster providing ETH once tokens are transferred to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackup has an example of an ERC-4337 transaction, including paymasters: https://docs.stackup.sh/docs/guides/quickstart

There is also a Tutorial from zkSync [here](https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/tutorials/custom-paymaster-tutorial.html).